# Qlikview store to CSV in script load problems with management console reload

Tags: qlikview

I have seen several threads on the subject of macros to fire file extracts not working in the QV management console reload, and suggested workarounds include using store to CSV in the load script and external commands.

My preference is to use the store to CSV in the load script, and it works on debugging and on reload generated from my PC, but will not execute from the server management console reload.

Is this a permissions issue that can be resolved? Do not wish to set up an external command which will be dependent on scheduling on my PC.

Any observations/solutions out there?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Store command then you will need to ensure the account the server service runs under has permissions to the destination folder.

For example if you have something like the following then the QlikView server service account needs to have write access to \myserver\share:
*store myTable into \myserver\share\myfile.txt (txt);*

If you are not sure what account needs these permissions then you can find this out in the QlikView Management Console under System > About (click More details and look for username associated with QlikView process).

Hope this helps.

Rod

Comment: I am not au fait with server accounts or permissions. I would have imagined that code in  a document stored on the Qlikview server with Store to code written to a csv file located on the same Qlikview server should not encounter permission issues, but it still does not work....